# gtalk(XMPP) initial response not always contain a <stream:features>

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

i send to talk.google.com with a initial stanza like:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<stream:stream
from='XXXXXX@gmail.com'
to='gmail.com'
version='1.0'
xml:lang='en'
xmlns='jabber:client'
xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'>
```

and as the rfc6120 said, server should response with a stanza that has tag named "stream:features"

but I've tried a lot of time but the response rarely contained the "stream:features" so I have to make a circulation waiting for a response which contains a "stream:features".

Comment: I'm wondering if there is something I missed or misinterpreted about XMPP protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get a `stream:stream` open tag before the `stream:features`:

```
<stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" 
               xmlns="jabber:client" 
               from="gmail.com" 
               id="407014FD9646082B" 
               version="1.0">
  <stream:features>
    <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls">
      <required/>
    </starttls>
    <mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
      <mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism>
      <mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism>
    </mechanisms>
  </stream:features>
```

I'd urge you to use one of the existing client libraries linked to at [xmpp.org](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/).  You're likely to have a bunch of other problems before you've got something running well if you're doing synchronous reads.

Comment: finally I find there might be some postpone between stream:stream and stream:features, maybe I should resort to some libs to get things work.